# Is it possible to switch between text views based on language?

Tags: android, right-to-left

I'm trying to find a way to switch between text views based on language, because some languages like hebrew and arabic are from right to left, so if I have two text views for example first text view says Park Name: and the second one says  Central park which sums it up to Park Name: Central Park, I need to reverse that to Central Park :Park Name, which concludes to just swapping their location, any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the layout?
If you use RelativeLayout, then you'll find

```
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" // for the Park Name
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" // for the Central Park
```

Thus will automatically swapping the location based on language